# puppeteer set window position after launch

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I want to dynamically reposition the window after launching puppeteer browser.
But I couldn't find a way anywhere.
How can I do this in puppeteer?

In selenium, something like this:

```
driver.manage().window().position = new point(100,200);
```

Comment: Could you try passing using these Args in the LaunchOptions? "--window-size=1920,2160", "--window-position=0,0"

Comment: @hardkoded Thanks for the comment. However, I do not want to set the browser start position. While navigating using a puppeteer browser, I want to change the position of the window to a specific position at the moment I want.

Comment: I think that won't be possible. What's your use case? what do you need that?